# setting precision in legend notation in matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

I have this:

```
leg2=strcat('Max Degree :',num2str(adet(1,1)/ch(l)));
leg3=strcat('Min Degree :',num2str(adet(1,2)/ch(l)));
leg4=strcat('Max Request :',num2str(adet(1,3)/ch(l)));
leg5=strcat('Min Request :',num2str(adet(1,4)/ch(l)));
leg6=strcat('Max Priority :',num2str(adet(1,5)/ch(l)));
leg7=strcat('Random :',num2str(adet(1,6)/ch(l)));
leg8=strcat('AICS :',num2str(adet(1,7)/ch(l)));
legend(leg2,leg3,leg4,leg5,leg6,leg7,leg8,'Location','SouthWest');
```

Here, `adet(1,1)/ch(l)` is a number between 0 and 1. And sometimes it becomes something like `0.01666667`. I'd like to set a precision for it to make it something like "0.02".

I can do it with `disp()` function with the `format bank`. But I don't know how to apply it in a plot. and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a format specifier in [`num2str`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) (within the `legend` statement):

```
>> num2str(pi) %// default
ans =
3.1416
>> num2str(pi, '%.2f') %// two decimal figures
ans =
3.14
```

Comment: wow. just like c++ we know. I didn't know that:) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's the same idea. You could also use [`sprintf`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), if you come from C