# How to show exactly three digits after decimal in legend bar when the values are created by linespace in Matlab

Tags: matlab, decimal, rounding

I have one stupid question. I have a range of value like:

```
N=linspace(1,2,15);
```

Now, I want to show these computed N value with exactly three digits after decimal in the legend bar. I have written this code:

```
N_rounded = round(N * 1000) / 1000;
```

and finally in the figure I set this value for Yticklable:

```
set(h,'Yticklabel', N_rounded);
```

but the value which is shown in legend bar didn't show exactly 3 digits after decimal. for example it shows 1.5 instead of showing 1.500. I need to show 1.500 How can I do that?

br,

Comment: Try `set(h,'Yticklabel', num2str(N_rounded, '%.3f'));`  http://stackoverflow.com/q/29103531/1566267

Comment: @John_West, THX pal but it didn't work :( please have a look at the below link which is the result of your suggested code 
http://s15.postimg.org/9iobh5m1n/legend1.png

Comment: Thx for pointing this! I have forgotten *space*. Posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `set(h,'Yticklabel', num2str(N_rounded, '%.3f\n'));`

Thanks some man (comment deleted) for the line break.

Comment: THX pal but still the same problem all values are shown in all bins.
http://s15.postimg.org/9iobh5m1n/legend1.png